# Joining two Access queries using SQL when one is a totals query: Access prompts for a param

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a large table `tblA` which I need to self-join.

The problem is that some of the items are repeating and need to be grouped.

So, I decided to to create two queries based on `tblA` and join them after having grouped the needed field. The result is two queries:

1. `qryNoTotals`
2. `qryTotals`

Now I join them and if I add the `Sum` aggregated field from `qryTotals` I get a prompt for a "Parameter". Leaving this blank just returns an empty field. If I leave out any aggregated fields from the join field list, query runs fine, but without the result I need.

What gives?

Details:

```
tblA (Milestone, Submilestone, Item_no, CoAmendmentNo, Event, Amount_USD, Component)
```

Here is some sample data populating it:

```
ID  Milestone   Submilestone    CoAmendmentNo   Event                   Amount_USD
5   2           1           17                Site Mobilization       $111.00
6   2           1           23                Site mobilization       $222.00
7   3           1           17                Notification of Work    $111.00
8   3           1           23                Notification of Work    $222.00
9   4           1           17                Excavation              $111.00
10  4           1           23                Excavation              $222.00
11  4           1           23                Excavation              $222.00
```

My goal is to self join every row on Milestone and Submilestone pair for each CoAmendmentNo and have Amount_USD for each pair of CoAmendmentNo values (17 and 23).

As you a see, rows 10 and 11 need to be aggregated, so that they can be joined with row 9 to produce a joined row in this form:

```
ID  Milestone   Submilestone    CoAmendmentNo_1 CoAmendmentNo_2  Event          Amount_USD_1 Amount_USD_2
            4           1           23          17               Excavation     $444.00      $111.00
```

Another complication is that I need to Outer join CoAmendmentNo=23, because there are items present in 23 which are not in 17.

So, I decided to join two separate queries instead of a long self-join with totals and an outer join.

query `qryNoTotals`:

```
 SELECT tblA.Milestone, tblA.Submilestone, tblA.CoAmendmentNo, tblA.Amount_USD, tblA.Event 
 FROM tblA 
 WHERE ((tblA.CoAmendmentNo)=17);
```

query `qryTotals`

```
 SELECT tblA.Milestone, tblA.Submilestone, Sum(tblA.Amount_USD) AS SumOfAmount_USD, tblA.CoAmendmentNo
 FROM tblA 
 GROUP BY tblA.Milestone, tblA.Submilestone, tblA.CoAmendmentNo 
 HAVING (((tblEPC_Ms_And_Events.CoAmendmentNo)=23);
```

finally I join both:

```
 SELECT qryTotals.Milestone AS 23Ms,
 qryTotals.Submilestone AS 23SMs,
 qryNoTotals.Milestone AS 17Ms,
 qryNoTotals.Submilestone AS 17SMs,
 qryNoTotals.Event AS 17Event,
 qryNoTotals.AmountUSD
 FROM qryTotals LEFT JOIN qryNoTotals 
 ON ((qryTotals.Milestone = qryNoTotals.Milestone)
 AND (qryTotals.Submilestone = qryNoTotals.Submilestone));
```

Running the above gives me Enter Parameter dialog box for `qryNoTotals.AmountUSD`. Entering nothing into it and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> produces a good join but leaves `qryNoTotals.AmountUSD` field values empty. I also want to add `qryTotals.AmountUSD` field to the Select clause, after figuring out the dialog box problem.

Comment: Your guess is as good as ours.  How can we help if we can't see the queries?

Comment: Show what you have tried so far...

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in two queries:

The `qryTotals` should be [note change: `HAVING (((tblA.CoAmendmentNo)=23)`]

```
SELECT tblA.Milestone, tblA.Submilestone, Sum(tblA.Amount_USD) AS    SumOfAmount_USD, tblA.CoAmendmentNo
FROM tblA 
GROUP BY tblA.Milestone, tblA.Submilestone, tblA.CoAmendmentNo 
HAVING (((tblA.CoAmendmentNo)=23);
```

And the join query should be [note change `qryNoTotals.Amount_USD`] :

```
SELECT qryTotals.Milestone AS 23Ms,
qryTotals.Submilestone AS 23SMs,
qryNoTotals.Milestone AS 17Ms,
qryNoTotals.Submilestone AS 17SMs,
qryNoTotals.Event AS 17Event,
qryNoTotals.Amount_USD
FROM qryTotals LEFT JOIN qryNoTotals 
ON ((qryTotals.Milestone = qryNoTotals.Milestone)
AND (qryTotals.Submilestone = qryNoTotals.Submilestone));
```